# Firestore Emulator not connect to localhost

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

i'm having a serious problem with my firestore emulator.

I exported production firestore data to emulator. This is fine, all the data in firestore is moved to the emulator and it shows.
The problem is, when i make changes to firestore emulator, the changes don't show on localhost. Localhost only has the initial firestore data. Everything else works, emulator auth work and i'm able to trigger functions when i make changes directly to local firestore data.

Is it possible that something is blocking connection to firestore emulator? Because the code works on its own and the emulator works on its own but there seems to be a disconnect locally, because in a live environment, things work.

package.json

```
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.11.0",
    "@faker-js/faker": "^7.6.0",
    "@firebase/rules-unit-testing": "^2.0.7",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.18.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@videojs/themes": "^1.0.1",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.10.3",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^11.30.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "fslightbox-react": "^1.7.6",
    "functions": "^1.0.9",
    "imagekitio-react": "^2.0.0",
    "lightbox.js-react": "^0.6.4",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.6",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.2.23",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "readline": "^1.3.0",
    "use-places-autocomplete": "^4.0.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^1.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "test:rules": "jest test --config=firebase.jest.config.js --detectOpenHandles --forceExit",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "emulators": "firebase emulators:start --project demo-test --import=./savedData --export-on-exit"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^8.3.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "webpack": "^5.84.1"
  }
}
```

I used this [page](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-import-production-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator-e82ae1c6ed8) to setup my emulators.

Comment: I'm not clear what's not working the way you expect. It would be helpful if you edit the question to show the specific steps you're taking to cause the problem. Anyone should be able to follow those same steps to reproduce the issue. Saying "when i make changes to firestore emulator, the changes don't show on localhost" isn't enough to know what the problem is.

Comment: I've discovered that my problem was how everything was structure in ```firebase.js```

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, you can post it as an answer and accept it as correct so that others with the same problem can be helped in the future.